# Could not find function from same package when using foreach (Windows devel)

Tags: r, parallel-foreach

Having a function using foreach for parallelization that is using another function in the same package used to be fine. But apparently, it is not anymore for R-devel on Windows??

I'm starting to see this problem is some of my packages so I decided to make a small reproducible example.

You can find a small package to reproduce the problem and the functions there: https://github.com/privefl/minipkg/blob/master/R/test-parallel.R.

You can see the check that fails there: https://github.com/privefl/minipkg/commit/973b2048d43a2c75fcee088f8182776f9cd1f95d/checks?check_suite_id=343796248#step:9:151.

Any idea where it comes from? Is it expected? What to change to make it work again?

---

Edit:
I've added more builds (see https://github.com/privefl/minipkg/runs/339575258);

- it does not fail on Mac with R-devel (and Linux fails for another reason)
- it also fails on Windows with R-3.6 (but not locally on my Windows laptop with R-3.6.1)
- but works fine on win-builder (https://win-builder.r-project.org/xoPf41nz47Dx/00check.log)
- works fine on Travis (https://travis-ci.org/privefl/minipkg/builds/623573771) and AppVeyor (https://ci.appveyor.com/project/privefl/minipkg/builds/29461832)

Comment: This used to work for you? I don't think it has ever worked for me.

Comment: Yes, it has always been working fine.

Comment: Also on win-builder? Could it be foreach updates - same with previous versions of foreach?  PS. Adding a summary of verified OS version, R version x.y.z, foreach x.y.z, doParallel x.y.z here on SO, would be useful (also for future visitors when your GitHub links might be gone)

Comment: What if you use `minipkg:::myfun` or include `parallel::clusterEvalQ(cl, {library(minipkg)})` before your foreach call?

Comment: @HenrikB Great suggestions. I tried with {foreach} v1.4.4 and it errors also. However, it does not error on win-builder R-devel (see update).

Comment: @SeGa Thanks for the suggestions. Yet, I fear it is not really allowed to use `:::` inside packages. Also `library(minipkg)` would not help as it is not an exported function. I could probably define the function inside the foreach loop but it would require me to change all my previous code. I just want to understand why it is not working anymore (while it has been working for 3+ years), and if I really need to make all these changes to my code.

Comment: Indead, `:::` will not pass the checks. I know that I was always using `::` for my package functions inside a `foreach` block, as I got the error that the function was not found too often.

Comment: @SeGa I do use `::` when using functions from other packages.

Comment: Someone had the same problem for one of my packages, on Linux and using Conda. He says "I eventually decided to delete my conda environment and reinstall your package in a clean environment. Somehow that worked.". I still don't understand what is the problem though.

Comment: So, the only place it fails for you is on the GitHub Action running R devel on Windows, correct?  If so, that is using `rcmdcheck::rcmdcheck(args = '--no-manual', error_on = 'warning', check_dir = 'check')`, which might not necessarily be the same as using plain `R CMD check`.  So, that's a potential lead.

Comment: @HenrikB Locally (Windows R-3.6.1), I get no error running `rcmdcheck::rcmdcheck(args = '--no-manual', error_on = 'warning', check_dir = 'check')`.

Comment: I would still run good old `R CMD check` on the problematic platform to rule out `rmdcheck`. Another thing I would do is to dump all environment variables and especially look at the `_R_CHECK_*` ones to see if there are differences.

Comment: Another, much wilder idea: it could somehow happen during the build. Download `minipkg_0.1.0.tar.gz` that was built on the problematic platform and  run `R CMD check` locally to see if you get the error.

Comment: @HenrikB Just tried that and it did not error locally.

Comment: @HenrikB I'm starting to wonder if it is a problem related to Conda, which seems to be used by builds in GH actions, and by the person reporting the issue on my package.

Comment: Sure, it could be specific to Conda, but my gut feeling tells me there is a simple explanation to it by the end of the day ... and you'll be able to reproduce it elsewhere too.  I think it's worth understanding what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error occurs because the foreach code needs to load the package in the child process, but the package is not installed before running the checks on GitHub Actions.

You can see the same result if you try to run `R CMD check` locally on a Windows machine without first installing the package into your library.

I believe it works on non-Windows systems without installing because the way that `R CMD check` handles the environment variables controlling the package libraries during R CMD check differs slightly on Windows than elsewhere.

Comment: Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Install the package on your system prior to running R CMD check.

Comment: Thanks, yes I installed it.